# Master's-level Quantitative Methods / Statistics textbook for Management, Marketing, Economics students

Tags: references, teaching

What are some good textbooks for a master's (or upper undergraduate) level course in Quantitative methods / Statistics for students in Management, Marketing or Economics?

Comment: In my case, the *Economics* part of *Management and Economics* is little quantitative, so I am mostly interested in textbooks that the less quantitatively capable students could live with.